# How to do ItemClick on HorizontalListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HorizontalListView1.1/

I used the above link and implemented Horizontal List. List is coming, it's scrolling horizontally. But, for Item click, I used two properties:

1. SelectedItem
2. SelectedItemChanged

But, still I did not get that how to do Item Click Event in this.

See the below code:

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollView  Orientation="Horizontal" ><StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
 <Controls:HorizontalListView x:Name="packages_listname" ListOrientation="Horizontal"  >
      <Controls:HorizontalListView.ItemTemplate SelectedItemChanged="Item_Changes">
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid Grid.ColumnSpacing="0">
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#282C2B" HeightRequest="60" Spacing="0" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                  <Label Text="{Binding Package_Name}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Margin="0"/>
                   </StackLayout>
                  </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
              </Controls:HorizontalListView.ItemTemplate>
            </Controls:HorizontalListView>
             </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
      </StackLayout>
```

**Code.Cs:**

```
packages_listname.ItemsSource = packageslist;
public void Item_Changes(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // var obj = ((HorizontalListView)sender).SelectedItem as PackagesModelClass;
    var obj = packages_listname.SelectedItem as PackagesModelClass;

        switch (obj.Package_Name)
        {
            case "Corporate":
                list_of_corporate.ItemsSource = GetData("Corporate");

                break;
            case "ValueAddGrid":
                list_of_corporate.ItemsSource = GetData("ValueAddGrid");
                break;
            case "UtilityGrid":
                list_of_corporate.ItemsSource = GetData("UtilityGrid");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to set the binding for `SelectedItemChanged` on your `HorizontalListView` instead of on your `ItemTemplate`. When reading the [source](https://github.com/softsan/HorizontalListView/blob/master/HorizontalListView/HorizontalListView/HorizontalList.cs), the `EventHandler` is defined for the `HorizontalListView` and not for the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: That Ok. But, How to do Item Click in Horizontal Listview?

Comment: I Could not find ItemClick property.